# Recursive print two lines for every call with Stairstep pattern

Tags: java, recursion, recursive-datastructures

I am working on a data structures problem. The assignment and what I have so far is listed below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random; 
/**
* Recursive methods for fun & profit
* 
* @author (your name) 
* @version (a version number or a date)
*/
public class DSLab2
{
/**
 * Prints 2 lines of text for each recursive call, indicating call number 
     * (a value >= 1, and <= value of numCalls, as illustrated below.  Each
     * level of recursion should be indicated by indenting the input line by
     * r spaces.  For example, if numCalls is 3, the method should print:
 *  call 1
 *   call 2
 *    call 3
 *    back 3
 *   back 2
 *  back 1
 *  @param r the level of method calls
 *  @param numCalls the number of intended levels
 */
public static void stairSteps (int r, int numCalls)
{
    System.out.println("call "+r);
    System.out.println("back "+r);
}
```

I have tried the following method, but it only outputs the bottom half of the stair-step requirement. I am not able to figure out how to call the method recursively such that the two lines are printed in each call **`without them being next to each other`**.

```
public static void stairSteps (int r, int numCalls)

if(numCalls>0)
   {

    for ( int i = 0; i <numCalls ; i++){
    System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("back " + r);
    stairSteps(r-1, numCalls-1); 
   }
   else
   return;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void stairSteps (int r, int numCalls)
{
    if ( numCalls==0 )
        return ;
    for (int i=0; i<r; i++)
        System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.println("call "+r);

    stairSteps(r+1, numCalls-1) ;

    for (int i=0; i<r; i++)
        System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.println("back "+r);
}

public static void main(String argv[]) {
    stairSteps(1, 4) ;
}



 call 1
  call 2
   call 3
    call 4
    back 4
   back 3
  back 2
 back 1
```

Comment: Thank you. But this gives the pattern but let's say call to stairSteps(5,6) i am getting the following result, which isn't correct.

call 5
      call 6
       call 7
        call 8
         call 9
          call 10
          back 10
         back 9
        back 8
       back 7
      back 6
     back 5

The count should be starting from 1.

Comment: how about this. save the first r var to global var gr. and print r-gr+1.

Answer (score 0):

You shall play with List & Stack data structures also as follows.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Main {

    private static List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private static Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        stairSteps(1,3);
        for(String s:list) System.out.println(s);
        while(!stack.isEmpty()) System.out.println(stack.pop());
    }

public static void stairSteps (int r, int numCalls)
{
    if(numCalls==0) return;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=1;i<r;i++) sb.append(" ");
    list.add(sb.toString()+"Call "+r);
    stack.push(sb.toString()+"Back "+r);
    if(r<numCalls) stairSteps(r+1, numCalls);
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I hope to learn about that soon. But for now, we haven't been taught stacks yet.